# Add Buttons at the end of each line, if quantity is more than zero, copy and paste to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to add buttons at the end of each line for products in Product List 1. The purpose to do so is when the quantity for the product is higher than zero, click the button, it will copy the Column B, E, F, G in Product List to the Order List worksheet. As there are lots product lines, when I click the button for another products, I tried to add 2nd one after 1st one rather than replace the 1st one in Order List, which I couldn't let it work. Here is the code below I did for first product on line 28, could you please take a look for me? Many thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_info()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
With Sheets("Order List")
.Cells.Clear
.Range("A1") = "PART CODE"
.Range("B1") = "DESCRIPTION"
.Range("C1") = "PRICE"
.Range("D1") = "QUANTITY"
.Range("E1") = "SHEET NAME"
.Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True
End With

j = 2

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     If sh.Name = "Product List 1" Then
        lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 28 To lastRow
            If sh.Range("G" & i) > 0 Then
               sh.Range("b" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order List").Range("A" & j)
               sh.Range("e" & i & ":g" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order List").Range("B" & j)
                Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j) = sh.Name
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
Sheets("Order List").Columns("A:E").AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Image of your data would help. Also, why are you looping all the sheets if you are only copying from one (to one other sheet)? You could simply test if that sheet to copy from is present and then run your code against that named sheet.

Comment: I was doing one click and adding all products with quantity over zero to a list, but I was told it was not good enough. I tried to remove the loop and it stops working. That is why I am thinking maybe someone here can give me some help. Many thanks